# Which material property to use when loading models with Assimp

Tags: assimp

When using Assimp to load models, some mesh materials have only color(COLOR_DIFFUSE, ...) or texture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, ...), but some models have both color and texture, which am I supposed to use or how am I supposed to combine the two?